# Powershell AD user account expires date export condition

Tags: powershell

I would like to insert a condition to check the AD user account expires date, how to implement it?

After selection, if the AD user account have fetch a value will expire in next day, then export the csv file.

Otherwise, ignore it and exit the program directly.

Thanks.

```
$Range = ((Get-Date).AddDays(1)).Date

Get-AdUser -Filter {AccountExpirationDate -eq $Range} –Properties AccountExpirationDate | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, Name, AccountExpirationDate | 
Export-CSV -Path "C:\Temp\Upcoming Retired User\Report_$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")).txt" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually using a Range of dates, but most of all, when you use `-eq`, you are checking if there are accounts that will expire tomorrow, exactly at midnight.

I don't think this is what you want to do and instead want to know which accounts are to become expired on or before the reference date.

Try

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(1).Date  # tomorrow at midnight
# try to find expired accounts
$users = Get-AdUser -Filter "AccountExpirationDate -lt $refDate" –Properties AccountExpirationDate -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($users) {
    $fileOut = Join-Path -Path 'C:\Temp\Upcoming Retired User' -ChildPath ('Report_{0:yyyyMMdd}.csv' -f (Get-Date))
    $users | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, Name, AccountExpirationDate | 
    Export-Csv -Path $fileOut -NoTypeInformation
}
else {
    Write-Host 'No expired accounts found'
}
```